# How can I get all subclasses of a class in Java?

Tags: java, class, reflection

So I have a class `A` and there are multiple classes that extend from class A. I create an instance of this class, is there a way to get all the other classes that extend A?

Something like:

```
A a = new A();
a.getAllSubclasses();
```

Only way I tought of doing this is scanning the entire project for all the classes and storing them in a list and then checking manuall if each class extends from A with instanceOf.

```
List<Class> classList;
classList.each{
    if(it instanceOf a)
        //do stuff
}
```

This seems bad especially for a huge project with hundred of classes.

Comment: you mean within a project, are globally?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: yes, the only way to know about "accessible" subclasses of class X ... is to scan the **complete** class path for all classes, and for each one check whether it is a subclass of X.

And note: of course that **only** tells you about subclasses in that class path.

In other words: there is always a restriction of scope. If you have two different projects, you can as well have some subclasses of X in both projects, so you would have to scan both these "contexts" to know about them.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple library called org.reflections give information about subclasses. Using this library, you need to call reflections.getSubTypesOf(ClassName)).
Check Respective code here [GitHub Code](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)